# Draw line between two different point

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to draw line between two points. Here is my code. but context memory is 0.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};

        CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 400);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
        CGColorRelease(color);
```

Comment: In what method are you trying this.?.,

Comment: What context memory? Are you sure your `context` variable is not `nil`?

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878821/how-to-draw-line-between-two-points

Comment: where did u put this code? it should be put in drawRect

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your code within a UIView subclass in the method `drawRect:`.
`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will get NULL (0) when your are not in a drawing context.

You might also check the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very useful tutorial for your need.

http://trailsinthesand.com/exploring-iphone-graphics-part-1/

Go through it once..!